# Error while compiling assets while deploying project to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment

I am new to ROR. I have finished creating my app and was trying deploy it onto heroku using git push heroku master. Below is the error that I get while performing push.

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing json 1.8.3
       Installing minitest 5.8.2
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing activesupport 4.2.4
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
       Installing loofah 2.0.3
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
       Installing actionview 4.2.4
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing actionpack 4.2.4
       Installing globalid 0.3.6
       Installing activejob 4.2.4
       Installing mime-types 2.6.2
       Installing mail 2.6.3
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.4
       Installing activemodel 4.2.4
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Installing activerecord 4.2.4
       Installing execjs 2.6.0
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.1.0.1
       Installing sass 3.4.19
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.5.1
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing railties 4.2.4
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
       Installing hoe 3.14.2
       Installing email_form_generator 1.0.5
       Installing multi_json 1.11.2
       Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
       Installing mail_form 1.5.1
       Installing mysql2 0.3.20
       Installing sprockets 3.4.0
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
       Installing rails 4.2.4
       Installing rdoc 4.2.0
       Installing tilt 2.0.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing simple_form 3.2.0
       Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
       Installing twitter-bootstrap-rails 3.2.0
       Installing uglifier 2.7.2
       Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 55 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Post-install message from twitter-bootstrap-rails:
       Important: You may need to add a javascript runtime to your Gemfile in order for bootstrap's LESS files to compile to CSS.
       **********************************************
       ExecJS supports these runtimes:
       therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby
       therubyrhino - Mozilla Rhino embedded within JRuby
       Node.js
       Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X
       Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript)
       **********************************************
       Bundle completed (38.64s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2015-11-08T17:03:09.207713 #1298]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/public/assets/style-0d5b3b0455ab9ba65ebe32a86e21555d4450dec914b7a0afa745eb5f5894a6dd.css
       I, [2015-11-08T17:03:10.617234 #1298]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/public/assets/jquery.min-02ff0ccffcd57eb8f53a39655db509a0cf9e9f98e20acd1434caf5645e2e228b.js
       I, [2015-11-08T17:03:10.984452 #1298]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/public/assets/cufon-yui-9c4d31adc3a9244d12c849264ba11fb36133a6994eabbd38c3ebe5e6674ada2e.js
       rake aborted!
       JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:130:in `block in find'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:129:in `each'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:129:in `find'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.4.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_bbd2a8ff0f85aebead85caa8937e84cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I tried precompiling it locally but error while doing this locally is different. See the image below.

[error while performing rake assets:compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxFWG.png)

What do I do? I have been searching for a solution for quite some time now and am unable to find one for the specific problem.

My application.css file contained *=require bootstrappl, so I removed to check whether it would work and it did. Now I am able to precompile the assets locally but am still unable to deploy it heroku encountering the same error.

JSON: :GenerateError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8

Please help.

If you need any any of my code, let me know.

Comment: do  you use only ASCII characters in your rails project? If not the problem can be with character encoding. Ruby uses system environment encoding for your files so it woks great on your system but heroku does use utf-8 which probably differs from your local setup. Just my guess.

Comment: Actually I don't know much about character encoding. So could you tell me what to do because come up against a wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your character encoding in Rakefile to correct one put:

```
#encoding: cp1250
```

on top of your Rakefile. (Replace cp1250 with your encoding).
And read something about the topic.